Service Stack - Security XSS Query following pentest
We recently had a penetration test done, and one of the "high" items was the fact that our servicestack API will reflect back user input unmodified to the caller.  E.g. I can send some script tags in to a GET request, and will get an error on back from the API with the script tags in it:

Has anyone else experienced this, or is there anything built in to servicestack to prevent it?
Thanks!

This is a JSON API Response, where is it being embedded in a HTML page to cause the XSS?

You can modify the Exception Message by overriding OnExceptionTypeFilter in your AppHost, e.g:
public class AppHost() : AppHostBase("My App"), IHostingStartup
{
    public override void OnExceptionTypeFilter(
        Exception ex, ResponseStatus responseStatus)
    {
        base.OnExceptionTypeFilter(ex, responseStatus);
        responseStatus.Message = Sanitize(responseStatus.Message);
    }
    //...
}


Great, good to know - thanks for the prompt answer as always!
